# Can I disable or suppress warnings about jupyter not being installed by the Jupyter vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'd like to use the Python extension for VSCode,
but it depends on the Jupyter extension (see Q&A [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/discussions/15723)).
I don't use Jupyter on most of my projects and therefore is not installed in my virtual environment.
This causes the Jupyter extension to keep popping up a warning which cannot be dismissed
that it "Failed to start a session" (because Jupyter is not installed).
Is there a setting in the extension that I have overlooked to suppress this warning?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm a developer on the Jupyter extension. It shouldn't be trying to start a kernel unless you are opening a .ipynb file. Are you seeing this error without opening a notebook file?

Comment: @IanHuff Yes indeed there are no notebooks in this project whatsoever

Comment: Could you try turning the setting Jupyter->Disable Jupyter Auto Start to true? We have code that tries to autostart a jupyter server or kernel (if you used it before) early. Might be what is causing the issue here.

Comment: @IanHuff Yup this gets rid of it

Comment: Do you want to write this down as an answer? I'll then mark it as solution

Comment: Added as an answer. Thanks for verifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try turning the setting Jupyter->Disable Jupyter Auto Start to true? We have code that tries to autostart a jupyter server or kernel (if you used it before) early. Turning this off should suppress the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

File > Preferences > Settings
Now expand "Text Editor"
"Suggestions"
"Edit in Settings.json"

Now you can disable all notifications or only for an extension.

Comment: I think this would disable code suggestions but not these error messages